# nginx redirection to another server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I compiled the nginx 'echo-nginx-module' module to log the request body.
My goal is to log and reverse proxy all the traffic coming to nginx to another DNS.
I am using proxy_pass to redirect the traffic to the second DNS and it successfully started to log the traffic body.
However, what's missing is I also need to log the traffic header and timestamp.
I've added the lines below to the proxy_pass config file and it does not seem to log headers. What am I missing?

```
location / {

    # the below four lines do not log header and body
    echo "headers are:"
    echo $echo_client_request_headers;
    echo_read_request_body;
    echo $request_body;

    # this works and logs traffic envelope
    proxy_pass https://offexserver-test-internal.leapaws.com.au;
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: So you want to redirect all `http` to `https` ?

Comment: yes, and to another DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this

```
http {
  log_format custom '$request_body';

  server {    
    server_name default_server;
    listen 80;
    location / {
      echo_read_request_body;
    }      
  }
}
```

You cannot log all the headers, the only thing you can do is, specify the headers individually you want to log. or you will have to use an additional [module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981036/4160532) to configure headers.

Comment: return is a client side redirection and it didn't work in my case to redirect to the second DNS and wait for it to respond. It worked though, when I used proxy_pass instead to redirect to the second DNS. It logs the traffic envelope. Now, what I want is to log the header and timestamp as well. Do you know what's missing from my config?

Comment: _**You want to log the header**_, do you want to log everything that comes in header ? _**timestamp**_ of, when the request was made ?

Comment: I want to log both the header and the body.

Comment: @Kedamang Yes, log everything in the header. If just whatever it logs by default if that's easier to log.