# How to include specific request header in access.log?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to include a request header of name `My-Key` into access log

I tried to add it as `"$http_My-Key"`:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_My-Key" "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                          '"$request_time" "$upstream_connect_time" "$upstream_header_time" "$upstream_response_time"';
```

however, it access log for that header, I get this value `"--Key"` logged:

```
X.X.X.X - - [22/Jul/2020:10:26:18 +0000] "POST /v1/my/app HTTP/1.1" 404 732 "--Key" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36" "X.X.X.X" "0.009" "0.004" "0.008" "0.008"
```

instead of the expected value `my test` which I sent with postman, any idea why?

Comment: I believe that you should first `set $myKey $http_MyKey;` and only then `log_format main "$remote_addr $myKey";` Otherwise you may need OpenResty as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981036/5962802

Comment: I am trying to imitate the already logged header: `$http_x_forwarded_for` , so I used the same syntax $http_<header>, is there a naming convention to follow? maybe it should be $http_My_Key rather than camel case as you suggested? as actual key name is: `My-Key`

Comment: Then you should try `set $myKey $http_my_key;`

Comment: Thanks, I will try now..

Comment: Hyphens are mapped to underscores in variable names.

Comment: Well, I just had to add `$http_my_key` into the `log_format main` value, and it worked, it was naming convention issue.. thanks