# Lua - Concatenation of variables (pairs) escaping special characters - Openresty Nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, string-concatenation, openresty

I don't use Lua, but need to use it with Openresty (nginx) as provided in the link.

**Openresty has a lua module** *which I managed to install and run the Openresty nginx version correctly, the website working.*

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689741/13632900) shows how to concatenate headers into a string `$request_headers`:

```
set_by_lua $request_headers '
  local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
  local request_headers_all = ""
  for k, v in pairs(h) do
    request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. "["..k..": "..v..\n"]"
  end
  return request_headers_all
';
```

I changed the format from `""..k..": "..v..";"` to `"["..k..": "..v.."]"` in the lua function above.

Log format:

```
log_format log_realip 'Host: "$host", Via : "$http_via", RemoteAddr: "$remote_addr", XForwardedFor: "$h
ttp_x_forwarded_for", 'RealIPRemoteAddr: "$realip_remote_addr" - $status - "$request_uri" - **"[HEADERS]" - $request_headers';**
```

```
Host: "192.168.1.4", Via : "-", 
//trimmed just to show the [HEADERS]
....
"[HEADERS]" - [sec-ch-ua: \x22Chromium\x22;v=\x2288\x22, \x22Google Chrome\x22;v=\x228
8\x22, \x22;Not A Brand\x22;v=\x2299\x22][sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0][cookie: __utmz=abcdef; frontend=abcdef; adminhtml=abcdef
08; TestName=Some Value][upgrade-insecure-requests: 1][accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9][user-agent: Mozilla/5.0
 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36][accept
-encoding: gzip, deflate, br][accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/we
bp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9][sec-fetch-dest: document][host: 192.168.1.4][se
c-fetch-user: ?1][connection: keep-alive][sec-fetch-mode: navigate][cache-control: max-age=0][sec-fetch-site: n
one
```

When using `log_format` with `$request_headers` string I get all the headers *in one line*, but I am trying to create a `newline \n` to break the string into lines.  The example above is where I added `\n` but doesn't seem to output break to the log file.

I understand the `request_headers_all ..` concatenates the string, but what is happening here with the `key k` and `value v` : `""..k..": "..v..\n""`?

What is the `"..variablename.."` doing, is this how variables are always used inside Lua strings?

How would I be able to create a line break in that string?  Or is it possible that nginx(openresty) doesn't output the newline?

Comment: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#special-escaping-sequences TL;DR: use `set_by_lua_block {}`

Comment: I wish you answered earlier ;) ...only required to use _double escaping_ sigh!
I came up with the same conclusion that I needed `set_by_lua_block` after investigating further.  I used `string.format`, but if I realised _double escaping_ can work would have been easier! I never saw your message until now after I replied with my solution.  For anyone else see my answer below : `1. set_by_lua_block` and `2. log_format escape=none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answers gave me some guidance, but the formats suggested still didn't work.  After playing around with `string.format("%s %s\n", k, v)`, `string.format("%s %s\\n", k, v)` I still got `unfinished string` errors or no newline output.  (Tried to escape string in second example).

Based on the answers given I assumed the answers gave correct lua information, so decided most likely `lua + openresty` does something different.

*I will attempt to update the title to reflect more specific requirements*

#### TLDR

0. `Openresty + lua` string manipulation with special characters might not work as expected, even when using `string.format()`
1. Change from `set_by_lua` which returns a string to `set_by_lua_block` which allows `string.format()` or string concatenation better.
2. Update nginx configuration with your custom/existing `log_format` and add the switch `escape=none`.

#### Full Explanation

Investigating the provided link answer `set_by_lua` function documentation :

> NOTE Use of this directive is discouraged following the v0.9.17 release. Use the set_by_lua_block directive instead.

So from the original `set_by_lua` from the link:

```
set_by_lua $request_headers '
  return 'stringvalue'
';
```

I changed to `set_by_lua_block` function:

> this directive inlines the Lua source directly inside a pair of curly braces ({}) instead of in an Nginx string literal (which requires special character escaping)

```
set_by_lua_block $request_headers{
  local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
  local request_headers_all = ""
  for k, v in pairs(h) do
    local rowtext = ""
    rowtext = string.format("[%s %s]\n", k, v)
    request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. rowtext

  end
  return request_headers_all
}
```

The important part is that this `_block  {}` function escapes the special characters correctly.

After that I received output in the log files as : `x0A` (newline character literal).

The final step then is to update the `nginx.conf` file with the custom `log_format` and add `escape=none`:

```
log_format log_realip escape=none "$nginx_variables"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. "["..k..": "..v..\n"]"
```

contains a syntax error.  replace `"["..k..": "..v..\n"]"` with `"["..k..": "..v.."]\n"`

Newline needs to be inside the quotes as it is part of the string and it will probably make sense to add the new line after the bracket.

> What is the "..variablename.." doing, is this how variables are always
> used inside Lua strings?

using the concatenation operator on a variable concatenates a string value, concatenates its string representation if it is a number or invokes `__concat` or raises an error if neither of those is true.

Read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.6

Comment: As with the other answer above:

I am 100% sure I tried that format as well.  
Just to make sure I copied your format : `failed to load inlined Lua code: set_by_lua:5: unfinished string near '"]', client: 192.168.1.3, server: 192.168.1.4, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.4"`.

In essence I agree with your observation that `\n"]" should not work because it's 'part of the variable output'... but it doesn't crash the page.  Your solution gives the error I just displayed.  

This behaviour is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Your explanation helps me understand the various different behaviour depending on the type.   I will investigate on how to edit the string to make openresty understand the string correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you add the `\n` to a wrong place, you can change to
`request_headers_all = request_headers_all .. "["..k..": "..v.."]\n"` for a newline log.

In lua, the `..` is a concat operator, to concat to strings, for example:

```
print("hello" .. "world")
```

get the result `helloworld`.

your code `\n"]"` have syntax error, because `\n` not in a string.

lua strings can not directly use variables, usually, lua use `string.format` for complex string. for example:

```
local test = "hello"
string.format("%s world",test) -- hello world
```

you can use string.format for you string concat.
also, you can use `table.concat`  to concat strings.
for example:

```
local test = {}
table.insert(test, "hello")
table.insert(test, "world")
local concated_string = table.concat(test, ' ')
print(concated_string) -- hello world
```

Comment: I am 100% sure I tried that format as well.  
Just to make sure I copied your format : `failed to load inlined Lua code: set_by_lua:5: unfinished string near '"]', client: 192.168.1.3, server: 192.168.1.4, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.4"`.

In essence I agree with your observation that `\n"]" should not work because it's 'part of the variable output'... but it doesn't crash the page.  Your solution gives the error I just displayed.  

This behaviour is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: I will investigate how to close the `unfinished string` further.

Comment: I will try `string.format` or `table.concat` to see if any of them will work better in _Openresty_ blocks

Comment: The unfinished string error was easy to found if you copy you lua code to a editor with syntax prompt like vscode. your error `unfinished string near '"]'` seems lack of the last `"`

Answer (score 1):

The main question/problem here is how does the wrapper software handle newline characters/escapes, is it expecting `"\n"`? or is it expecting `"\r\n"`?

Ultimately the new line does not actually exist until it is interpreted and printed and you are creating one massive string that gets returned from the Lua engine to the wrapper, so it is up to the wrapper software on how to interpret new lines.

Edit: I missed that this was already answered by using the other parsing function.

Additionally the docs state to use the original parsing function escapes need to be double escaped.

> `Here, \\\\d+ is stripped down to \\d+ by the Nginx config file parser and this is further stripped down to \d+ by the Lua language parser before running.`

Comment: Thank you Kirin ;)  As already explained, I have tried those formats as well - `"\n"` outside the array, which makes sense to all of us, (I am aware my original example shows it inside!).  Thanks for the explanation.... but : `The main question/problem here is how does the wrapper software handle newline characters/escapes, is it expecting "\n"? or is it expecting "\r\n"?`.  This is where the issue is: Openresty+lua (_wrapper software_) probably handles it strangely.  I found the solution with the other function in Openresty.  But yes the core issue - based on my original example ...

Comment: .... everyone (including even me in the future) would assume I made a mistake on the original question with the format.  _I tried several different types, none worked_.  Had to use the other Openresty function.

Comment: Ohh my bad, I see it now, to do it using your original implementation you double escape it so it would be \\\\n according to the docs. "