# How to pass variable value from js file to nginx config with njs module

Tags: nginx, njs

I am trying to use njs to have chain request with nginx njs, i have below issue
here is my javascript file and my scenario is
I have two of API.
I want to request first api and get it's reponse then append first api's response (cloud be JSON properties )  second api's header

```
async function chain(r) {
  r.headersOut["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  var result = await r.subrequest("/validation", { method: "POST" });
  var json = JSON.parse(result.responseText);

  headers = json.fullName;// where to put this header and append it to second request header ?
  var result1 = await r.subrequest("/persistance");

  r.return(result1.status, result1.responseBody);

}

function getHeaders() {
  return headers;
}

export default { chain, getHeaders };
```

And my nginx config file

```
js_import http.js;
js_set $headers http.getHeaders; // here am trying to get headers from variable in http.js but is it alwat null and undefended
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
       
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
       
    location ~ ^/.*$ {
      js_content http.chain;
    }

    location = /persistance {
       proxy_set_header accountId $headers; //it is always undefined, I think it is because declared on the top of file and it is nginx directives
       proxy_pass http://192.168.2.76:5001/academicyear/list;      
    }
     
    location = /validation {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.2.76:8088/v1/user/validation;
    }

}
```

I use **subrequest** and **then** it was the same issue

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380123/how-to-log-all-headers-in-nginx

Answer (score 1):

This comment might be the answer.

[image]

> nginx does not support asynchronous operations (it is not related to the async keyword in JavaScript) in its variable handlers. When nginx wants the value of some variable (say $x_js_log) it finds it and calls its handler (js_log). Nginx cannot block here, and wants the result right away. r.subrequest() is an asynchronous operation by its nature.

https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/287#issuecomment-584247289